# ValueError: need more than 0 values to unpack(python lists)

Tags: python, sequencing

I'm getting an error while I'm writing my code

```
tmp = c.pop(0) # taking out the first element from the list as the starting point
complete = tmp[0][-1]
print(complete)

while c != []:
    complete += tmp[1][-1]
    [index] = []
    for i, pair in enumerate(c):
        if pair[0] == tmp[1]:
            [index].append(i)
    temp = c.pop(index)

print(complete)
```

I'm getting this error in the `[index] == []` part:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
ValueError: need more than 0 values to unpack
```

My question is, why is this error coming up and how should I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Python, even if the variable contains a list, it should be used as a regular variable like `index = []`. When you use `[index] = []` Python thinks you want to assign the first item of the list to your variable.Likewise, when you use the code `[first, last] = [1,2]`, then the variable `first` is assigned 1 and the variable `last` is assigned 2. This is called unpacking.

Also, in `[index].append(2)`, you should not use the square brackets around the variable name. This would not raise any errors, but what it would do is create a new list (with the sole item being the value of `index`) and then destroy the list when the line has executed.

Your code should look like this (Assuming the other parts of your code are correct). Also, as [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29584964/valueerror-need-more-than-0-values-to-unpackpython-lists/29584979#comment47318288_29584979) suggested, use `c` instead of `c != []` because an empty list is false and it follows Python conventions. :

```
tmp = c.pop(0) # taking out the first element from the list as the starting point
complete = tmp[0][-1]
print(complete)

while c: # c != []
    complete += tmp[1][-1]
    index = [] # [index] = []
    for i, pair in enumerate(c):
        if pair[0] == tmp[1]:
            index.append(i) # [index].append(i)
    temp = c.pop(index)

print(complete)
```

As noted in the comments, the line `temp = c.pop(index)` will give an error because pop expects an integer and the code is giving it a list.

However, because of the OP's usage of `index` in the code, I think he meant to use index as a integer. Also, the OP stated that the usage of `temp` instead of `tmp` was a mistake.

```
tmp = c.pop(0) # taking out the first element from the list as the starting point
complete = tmp[0][-1]
print(complete)

while c:
    complete += tmp[1][-1]
    index = 0
    for i, pair in enumerate(c):
        if pair[0] == tmp[1]:
            index = i
    tmp = c.pop(index)

print(complete)
```

Comment: It seems to me that the convention is to use no enclosing punctuation (or parentheses, if you must) on the left side of an unpacking assignment. Also, use `if c` instead of `if c != []`, and check out the [official Python style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

Comment: @jake, by taking the [] out from index, i get TypeError: 'list' object cannot be interpreted as an integer, I might try to navigate this code in some other way i guess.

Comment: @Jessi In your while loop. The `if` is implied.

Comment: @Jessi For your second error, which line? BTW, surround text with backquotes ( ` ) to make something in `code`.

Comment: @Jessi Oh, I see. The `temp = c.pop(index)` line is giving you that error. That is because you are trying to pass in a list when the function is expecting a integer. I have no idea what you were trying  to do in that line. Can you explain?

Comment: @jake temp = c.pop(index) <- this line, since I'm appending my index with i(value), it won't let me use index inside c.pop

Comment: @Jessi I think you mean to use an integer variable for `index` .

Comment: @jake  I'm using nested lists [[],[],[],[]....] like this and I'm taking thesub list out of my outer list

Comment: I would recommend changing your names to make them better reflect their values—don't use `index` for a list of lists, for example.

Comment: @ jake, yea but its my first time using the stackflow, so i'm not familiar with the interface, should I copy to here?

Comment: @Jessi Have you read the little links that pop up when you post a question? Ex: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. For me, the top things you can have are: the code you need to replicate it, example user inputs and expected outputs, **Full** TraceBack errors, purpose and example values for variables not declared in the code.

Comment: c = [['TACA', 'ACAG'], ['CAGA', 'AGAT'], ['AGAT', 'GATT'], ['ATTA', 'TTAC'], ['ACAG', 'CAGA'], ['GATT', 'ATTA'], ['TTAC', 'TACA']] and the expected results are GATTACA, ATTACAG, TTACAGA,TACAGAT,ACAGATT,CAGATTA,AGATTAC any one of this since I'm using set() in the top of my code, I'm trying to concatenate segments of DNA to make a complete sequence of DNA.

Comment: @Jessi is it intentional that you use both `tmp` and `temp` in your code?

Comment: @ jake no , a mistake, it is tmp

Comment: I'm getting the right answer, thanks for the help jake, awsome help!!

Comment: @Jessi Great time with you too. Next time, try to include more information into your question. You gave a lot of useful information in the comments that should have included in the question